# Python Pandas KMeans: clustering a un tipo dataFrameGroupBy

Tags: python, pandas

Quiero pasar a `KMeans.fit(X)` un argumento de tipo `dataFrameGroupBy`, pero recibo este error:

> ```
> ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
> ```

¿Sería convertir el `dataFrameGroupBy`en un array multidimensional la única solución o existe alguna mejor?

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/406255/valueerror-setting-an-array-element-with-a-sequence)

Answer (score 0):

El problema se encontraba en que los grupos no tenían todos el mismo tamaño. Y KMeans así lo requiere.

Comment: Trata de detallar mejor tu respuesta, podría servirle a alguien en el futuro.