# ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence

Tags: python, array, numpy, machine-learning, tensorflow

Estoy intentando hacer un ejemplo de entrenar una red en `Tensorflow` Python para que al darle por código una imágen de un deporte, nos diga de que deporte se trata.

- Version Tensorflow: 2.2.0
- Versión Keras: 2.2.0
- Versión Numpy: 1.19

Este es mi código:

```
dirname = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'sportimages')
imgpath = dirname + os.sep 

images = []
directories = []
dircount = []
prevRoot=''
cant=0

print("leyendo imagenes de ",imgpath)

for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(imgpath):
    for filename in filenames:
        if re.search("\.(jpg|jpeg|png|bmp|tiff)$", filename):
            cant=cant+1
            filepath = os.path.join(root, filename)
            image = plt.imread(filepath)
            images.append(image)
            b = "Leyendo..." + str(cant)
            print (b, end="\r")
            if prevRoot !=root:
                print(root, cant)
                prevRoot=root
                directories.append(root)
                dircount.append(cant)
                cant=0
dircount.append(cant)

dircount = dircount[1:]
dircount[0]=dircount[0]+1
print('Directorios leidos:',len(directories))
print("Imagenes en cada directorio: americano(", dircount[0], "), basket(", dircount[1], "), beisball(", dircount[2], "), boxeo(", dircount[3], 
        "), ciclismo(", dircount[4], "), f1(", dircount[5], "), futbol(", dircount[6], "), golf(", dircount[7], 
        "), natacion(", dircount[8], "), tenis(", dircount[9], ")")
print('suma Total de imagenes:',sum(dircount))
labels=[]
indice=0
for cantidad in dircount:
    for i in range(cantidad):
        labels.append(indice)
    indice=indice+1
print("Cantidad etiquetas creadas: ",len(labels))
deportes=[]
indice=0
for directorio in directories:
    name = directorio.split(os.sep)
    print(indice , name[len(name)-1])
    deportes.append(name[len(name)-1])
    indice=indice+1

y = np.array(labels)
X = np.array(images, dtype=np.uint8) #convierto de lista a numpy
    
# Find the unique numbers from the train labels
classes = np.unique(y)
nClasses = len(classes)
print('Total number of outputs : ', nClasses)
print('Output classes : ', classes)
```

Al ejecutar estas últimas 7 líneas me da el siguiente fallo, que al ejecutar por primera vez no me dió:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-11fa738204d8> in <module>
      1 y = np.array(labels)
----> 2 X = np.array(images, dtype=np.uint8) #convierto de lista a numpy
      3 
      4 # Find the unique numbers from the train labels
      5 classes = np.unique(y)

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Querría saber que tengo que cambiar, o que fallo tengo para poder seguir con mi proyecto hacia delante.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esto es un error que se suele dar bastante en Python con el manejo de datos. Este error es lanzado por la librería `Numpy` y  basicamente tiene que ver con las asignaciones que se realizan en los espacios de memoria de tu ordenador. **En resumen**, sucede cuando `Numpy` **reserva espacios de memoria para un tipo de dato (int8, uint8, int32, float32, etc.) y después se entrega una secuencia (una lista, una tupla, etc.)**.

Vamos a ver en detalle que está sucediendo.

## Introducción al error

Vamos a analizar el significado de:

```
X = np.array(images, dtype=np.uint8)

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Este error nos está diciendo

> "Error de valor: estás introduciendo en un elemento de un array, una colección."

Es decir, `Numpy` está esperando un `np.uint8` y de repente le llega una colección. Puedo repetir este error haciendo lo siguiente:

```
import numpy as np
np.array([1, [2,3]], dtype=np.uint8)
```

**Salida:**

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

También lo puedo repetir haciendo esto:

```
import numpy as np
np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5]], dtype=np.uint8)
```

**Salida:**

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

## Explicación del error

La clave está en el funcionamiento de `Numpy`, en todos los casos le hemos indicado que los elementos a insertar en el array son **números enteros positivos en un rango de 0 a 255** `np.uint8`.

### Primer ejemplo

El primer array llega al primer elemento es un entero, perfecto. De repente llega al segundo y se **encuentra una colección de elementos**. Cuando a `Numpy` se le había indicado que le iban a llegar `np.uint8`. **Cuando trata de introducir la lista en el espacio que ha reservado para un elemento** `np.uint8` te lanza el error.

### Segundo ejemplo

`Numpy` esta **preparado para trabajar con distintos tipos de datos**, en el segundo ejemplo, `Numpy` lo que hace es ver la primera colección, se da cuenta que es una lista de tamaño tres y que por tanto **se va a formar una matriz de tres columnas y** *"N"* filas. De repente llega a la segunda colección y se encuentra que **solo hay dos elementos** (dos columnas) ¡Cuando debería de haber tres!

Al no cumplir este requerimiento, cuando trata de llenar el espacio de memoria reservado, introduce en el primer espacio, de nuevo una lista, pero no es posible, porque ese espacio está preparado para un `np.uint8`, vuelve a lanzar el error.

**Sin embargo si hago estás tres ejecuciones, no sucede el error.**

```
import numpy as np

#Fijamos un array de elementos
np.array([1,2,3], dtype=np.uint8)

#Fijamos un array con la misma forma
np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]], dtype=np.uint8)

#Podemos ver que esta es muy parecida pero sin fijar el tipo de dato
np.array([1, (2,3)])
```

1. En la primera `Numpy` espera que lleguen `np.uint8` y así es
2. En la segunda `Numpy` se da cuenta de que tiene que formar una matriz de 3 columnas conformada por `np.uint8` y así es
3. La tercera no le hemos especificado tipo ninguno, por lo que `Numpy` se da cuenta de que hay diferentes tipos, y pone por defecto que el array va a estar conformado por `np.object` es decir por distintos objetos. Por lo que `Numpy` *"curándose en salud"* reserva espacio suficiente en la memoria para ellos.

## Solución

Una vez llegado aquí ya seguramente sepas las soluciones a tomar, hay dos posibilidades.

1. Revisar el contenido en tu código de `images`, ya que probablemente no sean matrices con el mismo número de columnas, o están mal almacenadas las imagenes.
2. Quitar el `np.uint8` y dejarlo por defecto. Aunque luego la red neuronal te exigirá que todas las imágenes tengan la misma forma, por lo que será un problema en el futuro.